# Redirecting Pages that use cgi-bin in the url

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I'm having trouble redirecting urls that include cgi-bin in the path

Example:

http://website.com/cgi-bin/pc.storefront/en/product/product.aspx?iid=123

```
.htaccess
redirect 301 /cgi-bin/pc.storefront/en/product/product.aspx?iid=123 http://website.com/homepage.html
```

With that redirect the server returns: /cgi-bin/pc.storefront/en/product/product.aspx does not exist on this server error messaging.

However, if keeping everything the same and removing cgi-bin from the equation then the redirect works perfectly.

The server is apache2 using mod_rewrite. cgi is also disabled in httpd.conf. Are the any concerns related to redirecting cgi-bin?

Comment: Would RedirectMatch be a better declaration to use?

Comment: Look in the main server config for the cgi-bin alias/directive. I bet there is something there stomping/overriding your rewrite.

Comment: Mine has AllowOverride none and Options none. AllowOverride none means my .htaccess is completely ignored.

Comment: @Tim: Grep on httpd.conf returned: ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
# "/var/www/cgi-bin" should be changed to whatever your ScriptAliased
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">

Comment: It looks like there is a script alias for /var/www/cgi-bin/ and a directory. going to try commenting those lines

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is usually a default set of directives that come "out of the box" for more Apache configurations. This default often includes a `AllowOverride none` directive on the `cgi-bin` folder/alias. `AllowOverride none` means .htaccess files in the folder/alias will be ignored.

Try updating the main config directive to `AllowOverride Fileinfo`

Comment: Commenting out the directory and script alias worked. I'm not running anything in cgi-bin, just using the server for a php/mysql app. Is there any concern in commenting out the alias and directory?

Comment: Only concern is if you needed cgi-bin, commenting the whole directive opposed to just changing the AllowOverride disables the cgi-bin folder completely. Sounds fine for your case though.